# How to verify if a node in response body has unique value with postman?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, postman

The following is the response body of an API:

```
[
{
    "exercise_num": "1",
    "expire_date": "2019-03-11T16:31:17.935Z",
    "created_at": "2019-03-15T11:44:35.698Z"
},
{
    "exercise_num": "2",
    "expire_date": "2019-03-11T16:31:17.935Z",
    "created_at": "2019-03-15T11:44:38.363Z"
}
]
```

In Postman Tests, how to verify if exercise_num node in the response body above is unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter out unique `exercise_num` values and compare the length of the actual array and unique value array. Where you can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method for filtering unique values.

```
pm.test("Your test name", function() {
  var jsonData = pm.response.json();
  pm.expect(jsonData.reduce(function(arr, b) {
    if (!arr.includes(b.exercise_num)) {
      arr.push(b.exercise_num);
    }
    return arr;
  }, []).length).to.eql(jsonData.length);
});
```

Comment: Hi Pranav! Appreciate your quick response. I have tried the above code and postman throws the following error:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined"

Comment: @NoorYeaserKhan  :  I just updated, please check now

Comment: Thanks a bunch Pranav. It works perfectly fine now. Thank you so very much!